# Use 'range' command in Python and got TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program allowing run iteration using command psspy.change_vref, it changes Meas_Bus_Voltage[i] every time. This is my code:

```
print 'LengthOfData=',LengthOfData
for i in range(0,LengthOfData):
  print 'i=',i
  time_point=Time_Tag[i]

  if i>=1:
    psspy.powerflowmode() 

    print 'Meas_Bus_Voltage[i]=',Meas_Bus_Voltage[i]
    print type(Meas_Bus_Voltage[i])

    ierr,realaro = psspy.change_vref(1, '1', Meas_Bus_Voltage[i])
    ierr,realaro = psspy.change_gref(1, '1', Meas_Bus_Frequency[i])

    psspy.fact()
    psspy.dynamicsmode(0)

  psspy.run(0,time_point,10,10,0)
```

Then I got the error:

```
LengthOfData= 2000 i= 0 i= 1 Meas_Bus_Voltage[i]= 1.04118376974
ierr,realaro = psspy.change_vref(1, '1', Meas_Bus_Voltage[i])
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I use range here for i, it's from 0 to 2000, why it's not iterable?
Could anybody give me some help?

Comment: no, `i` is always an integer, a single value within the loop. that's the whole point of the `for` loop.

Comment: `psspy.change_vref` returns one value, not two.

Comment: @chepner: nope. in that case the error message would be `'int' object is unsubscriptable`

Comment: @KarolyHorvath actualy its a float, thats what the print shows

Comment: @FooBarUser: ?? not it isn't...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath his output prints this:  `Meas_Bus_Voltage[i]= 1.04118376974` even if it was an `int` he would get `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: @FooBarUser: ah, so you're talking to someone else then? I guess you wanted to address this to chepner.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath oops sorry

Answer (score 4):

Consider these two statements:

```
>>> def change_vref(): return 1
... 
>>> a,b = change_vref()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
>>>
```

As you can see, expecting two return values from a function that returns an `int` produces the error message you see.

Re-read your documentation to see what `psspy.change_vref()` returns.

Comment: This is a "community wiki" answer so I won't steal KennyTM's reputation.

Comment: If you did not come to that conclusion, then it is nice you marked it as community wiki. If you already knew what was the cause, marking it as community wiki was not necessary.

Comment: the Python syntax is:
ierr = change_vref(ibus, id, newval)
ibus and id is fixed number, what I need to modify is newval in every step.
This command change_vref gives vref(newval) and then run simulation. It says vref(newval) is array, but I change Meas_Bus_Voltage[i] it alos gives error.

Real NEWVAL Is the new value to be assigned to the VREF array entry associated with machine ID at bus IBUS (input; unchanged by default).

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> def f(n):
...     return 1


>>> a,b = f(2)
```

What is happening in the last line of code is sequence unpacking. Sequence is an iterable (e.g. tuple or list, but more generally it means that it has an iterator which can be used to iterate over it). So if only one value is returned you will get the error below which means a sequence was expected, but it was not received. :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```